# Make two thread plus an integer alternately

Tags: java, multithreading

I write the code below in order to plus an integer `n` with two threads alternately until `n` reach to `LIMIT`.

Sometimes it works well, but in most of time it doesn't, and both `t1` & `t2` are waiting.

I'm a beginner for Java concurrent programming. Could anyone point out my bug? Thanks in advance :-)

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
public class TwoThreads {
    private final int LIMIT = 500;
    private volatile int n = 0;

    public void runWithReentrantLock() {
        final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        final Condition t1CanRun = lock.newCondition();
        final Condition t2CanRun = lock.newCondition();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                while(n < LIMIT) {
                    lock.lock();
                    try {
                        t1CanRun.await();
                        if (n < LIMIT) {
                            n++;
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-->" + n);
                        }
                        t2CanRun.signal();
                    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        lock.unlock();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, "t1");

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(n < LIMIT) {
                    lock.lock();
                    try {
                        t2CanRun.await();
                        if(n < LIMIT) {
                            n++;
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-->" + n);
                        }
                        t1CanRun.signal();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        lock.unlock();
                    }

                }
            }
        }, "t2");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        lock.lock();
        t1CanRun.signal();
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TwoThreads instance = new TwoThreads();
        instance.runWithReentrantLock();
    }
}
```

[the right result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxSrY.png)

[the bad result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCAP3.png)

[the thread dump when result is bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDQR2.png)

Comment: Where your program output is text, you can post it into your question as text, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code stops sometimes is because the same thread takes the lock twice in a row (because there is nothing preventing that from happening). If you await after signalling, then this problem is solved.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class TwoThreads {
    private final int LIMIT = 500;
    private volatile int n = 0;

    public void runWithReentrantLock() {
        final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        final Condition t1CanRun = lock.newCondition();
        final Condition t2CanRun = lock.newCondition();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (n < LIMIT) {
                    lock.lock();
                    try {
                        if (n < LIMIT) {
                            n++;
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-->" + n);
                        }
                        t2CanRun.signal();
                        t1CanRun.await();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        lock.unlock();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, "t1");

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (n < LIMIT) {
                    lock.lock();
                    try {
                        if (n < LIMIT) {
                            n++;
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-->" + n);
                        }
                        t1CanRun.signal();
                        t2CanRun.await();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        lock.unlock();
                    }

                }
            }
        }, "t2");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TwoThreads instance = new TwoThreads();
        instance.runWithReentrantLock();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Can't Tell Yes, you are right. I realize there are serval race conditions in my code. Thanks a lot~